# Syntax error in SpARK SQL on running for loop

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below command works for one project..

```
%sql
CREATE GROUP testGroup_databricks WITH USER `bju.asd@xxx.com`;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW main.deltalake_db.Customers_Log_Table_RLS AS
 SELECT *
 FROM main.deltalake_db.Customers_Log_Table
 WHERE
   CASE
     WHEN is_account_group_member('users') AND requestProjectUrlName = "power-ops-dev" THEN TRUE 
     ELSE FALSE 
   END;
```

and then I would like to run the same command for multiple projects by running under a For loop something like this:

```
target_database = "main.deltalake_db"
distinctprojects = spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT requestProjectUrlName FROM main.deltalake_db.Customers_Log_Table")

for project in distinctprojects.collect():
    project_name = project['requestProjectUrlName']
    view_name = f"view_{project_name.replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_')}"
    groupname = f"users_{view_name}"
    create_group = f"""
    CREATE GROUP {groupname} with USER `bju.asd@xxx.com`
    """
    create_view_query = f"""
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {target_database}.{view_name} AS
    SELECT * FROM {target_database}.Customers_Log_Table
    WHERE 
      CASE
        WHEN is_account_group_member('{groupname}') AND requestProjectUrlName = '{project_name}' THEN TRUE 
        ELSE FALSE
    """ 
    try: 
        spark.sql(create_view_query)
        print(f"View {view_name} created successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating view {view_name}: {e}")
```

and I get error as parse syntax error at "WHEN". Not sure what is wrong? Anyone?

Comment: missing a `END`

Comment: my life is useless.. please post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a `END`.
check both query to see the difference.

BTW, it is useless to perform a `CASE WHEN` that returns true or false within a where clause.

```sql
 WHERE
   CASE
     WHEN is_account_group_member('users') AND requestProjectUrlName = "power-ops-dev" THEN TRUE 
     ELSE FALSE 
   END;

-- TO BECOME 

WHERE is_account_group_member('users') 
AND requestProjectUrlName = "power-ops-dev"
```

or for the python part :

```py
    create_view_query = f"""
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {target_database}.{view_name} AS
    SELECT * FROM {target_database}.Customers_Log_Table
    WHERE 
      CASE
        WHEN is_account_group_member('{groupname}') AND requestProjectUrlName = '{project_name}' THEN TRUE 
        ELSE FALSE
    """ 

# TO BECOME

    create_view_query = f"""
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {target_database}.{view_name} AS
    SELECT * FROM {target_database}.Customers_Log_Table
    WHERE is_account_group_member('{groupname}') 
    AND requestProjectUrlName = '{project_name}'
    """
```

*==> No more `END` issue with this syntax*

Comment: there are multiple When so using CASE.. didnt pasted the full in Question.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint Still, if the return of your case when is true or false, you do not need it in a where clause